# AngularJS ng-click doesn't work in digest cycle

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

Html:

```
<a href id="link "ng-click="print(arg)"> print </a>
```

Angularjs controller:

```
$scope.return_promise =function(arg){
 return $http.post('\path');
 )};

$scope.print = function(arg){
 url ="other/path/"
 $scope.return_promise(arg).then(function(r){
 if(r){
 $('#link').attr('href', url);
       });
 };
```

**Problem:** I checked with chrome debugger, the href actually updated, but the event doesn't trigger (i.e. not go to the url). If I click it again, it works.

If I add a statement `document.getElementById('#link').click()` at the end of `if` clause, it will prompt an error "digest cycle is in progress"

How can i solve this.

Comment: your code doesn't "go" anywhere, it only changes the `href`.  the second time you click it, the browser sees the `href` as having a value and goes there.  If you want to actually go there, you would need to tell it to in your code.  As a side note, you probably shouldn't be using jQuery to change the `href`, angular isn't always able to recognize changes by the external framework, though in this case, that's not what is causing the issue.

Comment: To go to the url better try with `$location` , and to access dom elements better try `angular.element()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question. First, check if the code you paste is the code you wanted add here, because it has numerous errors. If you would like to replace dynamically `href` attribute do it like so:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl as ctrl">
    <a href="ctrl.url" id="link "ng-click="ctrl.print(arg)">print</a>
</div>
```

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('module')
    .controller('SomeCtrl', SomeCtrl);

  SomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function SomeCtrl($scope) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.url = "#";

    vm.return_promise = function (arg) {
      return $http.post('/path');
    };

    vm.print = function (arg) {
      var url = "other/path/";
      vm.return_promise(arg).then(function (r) {
        if (r) {
          vm.url = url;
        }
      });
    };
  }
}());
```